# ParseException : cannot recognize input near 'where' 'rownum' '=' in subquery source in hive

Tags: hive, bigdata

ParseException : cannot recognize input near 'where' 'rownum' '=' in subquery  source in hive
Please help

ParseException : cannot recognize input near 'where' 'rownum' '=' in subquery  source in hive ParseException : cannot recognize input near 'where' 'rownum' '=' in subquery  source in hive please help me
ParseException : cannot recognize input near 'where' 'rownum' '=' in subquery  source in hive

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please add a question and generally more information. The full query would probably be help and also information about how the query is run. And remove the useless copy of the error messages. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `rownum` is not a keyword in hive. If you are using non hive SQL and expecting it to work in hive, you should change the SQL syntax before running it.